# column index out of range while creating a matrix

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am currently in the process of creating a dok matrix (no knowledge of the sensitivity matrix is ​​required for this). First I remove all users who bought less than 2 items. Then I split the data frame into test and train with 0.1%.

Now I put it into the matrix and unfortunately I get an error that it is IndexError: column index (98) out of range.

How do I remove this error?
Dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp

d = {'userid': [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
     'itemid': [715, 845, 98, 12324, 85, 715, 2112, 85, 2112, 852, 102, 85, 2112, 852, 98, 652]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

Methods

```
def remove_purchase_cleanded(df, value):
    return df[df['userid'].map(df['userid'].value_counts()) > value].reset_index(drop=True)

df_new = remove_purchase_cleanded(df, 2)   
print(df_new) 

def splitter(df, split):
    indices = np.random.permutation(len(df))
    test_size = int(len(df) * split)
    test_indices = indices[:test_size]
    train_indices = indices[test_size:]
    return df.iloc[train_indices], df.iloc[test_indices]


def generate_matrix(df_main, dataframe):
    mat = sp.dok_matrix((df_main.shape[0], len(df_main['itemid'].unique())), dtype=np.float32)
    for userid, itemid in zip(dataframe['userid'], dataframe['itemid']):
        mat[userid, itemid] = 1.0 # here is the error
```

Call of the methods

```
train, test = splitter(df_new, 0.1)

train = train.sort_values(by=['userid']).reset_index(drop=True)
test = test.sort_values(by=['userid']).reset_index(drop=True)
print(train)
print(test)

train_mat = generate_matrix(df_new, train) # here is the error

test_mat = generate_matrix(df_new, test)

# The error
IndexError: column index (98) out of range
```

Complete dataframe

```
    userid  itemid
0        0     715
1        0     845
2        0      98
3        1   12324
4        2      85
5        2     715
6        3    2112
7        3      85
8        4    2112
9        4     852
10       4     102
11       5      85
12       5    2112
13       5     852
14       5      98
15       5     652
```

Removed dataframe

```
    userid  itemid
0        0     715
1        0     845
2        0      98
3        4    2112
4        4     852
5        4     102
6        5      85
7        5    2112
8        5     852
9        5      98
10       5     652
```

Train dataframe

```
   userid  itemid
0       0     845
1       0     715
2       4     102
3       4    2112
4       4     852
5       5      98
6       5    2112
7       5      85
8       5     852
```

Test dataframe

```
   userid  itemid
0       0      98
```

Comment: Looking at the values in `df_main['itemid']` I don't see how  `len(df_main['itemid'].unique()))` as number of columns in `mat` could work? Maybe you intended more something like `df_main['itemid'].max() + 1` instead?

Comment: @Timus that worked! Thanks should I also change `df_main.shape[0]`?

Comment: The values you show as examples don't require it. But: I actually don't know what you're are doing, I've just looked at it from a technical angle. So I'm probably not qualified to give a proper answer :(